# Do more generalizations of Schur's inequality exist?

Tags: inequality

> I meet this following problem
>   If $$n\ge 3,\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\prod_{j\neq i}(a_{i}-a_{j})\right)\ge 0$$
>   where $a_{i}$ are real numbers.

when $n=3$, it is [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality)
 so which $n$ such this inequality?

but for  more generalization  form of Schur'.s Inequality exists?

Comment: For $n=3$, that looks like $a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2 \ge a_1 a_2 + a_2 a_3 + a_3 a_1$, which is as much Schur as it is rearrangement or AM-GM.

Comment: Further, for $n=4$, check $a_i = (9, 8, 4, 2)$ to get a contradiction, so that inequality isn't true even for positives.

Comment: Thank you, but $n\ge 5$ is also isn't true?

Comment: I haven't checked, but unless you have a strong reason to believe it will be, it may be a lot of ultimately fruitless effort.  There are other ways in which Schur is generalised - though really not found anything as elegant as the 3 variable case.

Comment: I  have find this paper: http://www.jwss.cc/?q=A+Schur+Type+Inequality+for+six++Variables+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I have solve it, this inequality it is only true for $n=3,n=5$ holds.

**For $n=3$ then inequality can write as**
$$(a_{1}-a_{2})(a_{1}-a_{3})+(a_{2}-a_{1})(a_{2}-a_{3})+(a_{3}-a_{1})(a_{3}-a_{2})=a^2_{1}+a^2_{2}+a^2_{3}-a_{1}a_{2}-a_{1}a_{3}-a_{2}a_{3}\ge 0$$
it is clear true

**for $n=5$,WLOG, we assume that**
$$a_{1}\ge a_{2}\ge a_{3}\ge a_{4}\ge a_{5}$$
**Lemma 1:**
$$I=(a_{1}-a_{2})(a_{1}-a_{3})(a_{1}-a_{4})(a_{1}-a_{5})+(a_{2}-a_{1})(a_{2}-a_{3})(a_{2}-a_{4})(a_{2}-a_{5})\ge 0$$
**Proof: because**
$$I=(a_{1}-a_{2})[(a_{1}-a_{3})(a_{1}-a_{4})(a_{1}-a_{5})-(a_{2}-a_{3})(a_{2}-a_{4})(a_{2}-a_{5})]$$
since
$$a_{1}-a_{3}\ge a_{2}-a_{3}\ge 0$$
$$a_{1}-a_{4}\ge a_{2}-a_{4}\ge 0$$
$$a_{1}-a_{5}\ge a_{2}-a_{5}\ge 0$$
$$a_{1}-a_{2}\ge 0$$
so
$$I\ge 0$$

**Use same methods we have**
$$(a_{5}-a_{1})(a_{5}-a_{2})(a_{5}-a_{3})(a_{5}-a_{4})+(a_{4}-a_{1})(a_{4}-a_{2})(a_{4}-a_{3})(a_{4}-a_{5})\ge 0$$
and
$$(a_{3}-a_{1})(a_{3}-a_{2})(a_{3}-a_{4})(a_{3}-a_{5})\ge 0$$
so for $n=5$ is hold

**for $n=4$, you can take** $a_{1}=0,a_{2}=a_{3}=a_{4}=1$

**for $n\ge 6$,you can take**
$$a_{1}=0,a_{2}=a_{3}=a_{4}=1,a_{5}=a_{6}=\cdots=a_{n}=-1$$
then $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\prod_{j\neq i}(a_{i}-a_{j})\right)=(-1)^3<0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here are some inequalities:

- **Schur's inequality**: If $a,b,c,p \geq 0$, then $$a^p(a-b)(a-c)+b^p(b-c)(b-a)+c^p(c-b)(c-a) \geq 0$$
- **Weak 6-variable Schur:** Suppose $a \geq b \geq c$, $x+z \geq y \geq 0$. Then $$x(a-b)(a-c)+y(b-c)(b-a)+z(c-b)(c-a) \geq 0$$
- **Strong 6-variable Schur:** Suppose $a \geq b \geq c$, $x+z \geq y \geq 0$. Then $$x^2(a-b)(a-c)+y^2(b-c)(b-a)+z^2(c-b)(c-a) \geq 0$$

Now we get to some inequalities with functions inside it. $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ be a function that can be expressed as the sum of monotonic non-negative functions. Let $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $h: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be odd (functions such that $f(x)=-f(-x)$) and increasing functions.

- **Vornicu-Schur inequality:** Let $a,b,c,x,y,z \in \mathbb R$, $a \geq b \geq c$ and either $x \geq y \geq z$ or $z \geq y \geq x$. Let $k$ be a postive integer. Then  $$f(x)(a-b)^k(a-c)^k+f(y)(b-a)^k(b-c)^k+f(z)(c-a)^k(c-b)^k \geq 0 $$

We get Schur's inequality if $k=1$, $x=a$, $y=b$, $x=c$, $f(n)=n^p$. But we can generalize further.

- **Weak generalized Schur inequality:** Let $f,g,h$ be defined as above and let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, $a \geq b \geq c$. Then $$f(a) g(h(a-b)h(a-c))+ f(b) g(h(b-a)h(b-c))+ f(c) g(h(c-a)h(c-b)) \geq 0$$
- **Strong generalized Schur inequality:** Let $f,g,h$ be defined as above and let $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, $a \geq b \geq c$. We further require $f$ to be convex. Then $$f(a)^2 g(h(a-b)h(a-c))+ f(b)^2 g(h(b-a)h(b-c))+ f(c)^2 g(h(c-a)h(c-b)) \geq 0$$

Comment: Where can I find the proofs of these generalized versions?